# Magento 2.2.2 order refund REST API Before Plugin get item order to refund

Tags: magento2.2.2, creditmemo, refund, before-plugin

Vendor\Module\Plugin\Order\Plugin.php:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Order;


class Refund
{

    /**
     * Create refund for invoice
     *
     * @param int $invoiceId
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoItemCreationInterface[] $items
     * @param bool|null $isOnline
     * @param bool|null $notify
     * @param bool|null $appendComment
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoCommentCreationInterface|null $comment
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoCreationArgumentsInterface|null $arguments
     * @return int
     * @since 100.1.3
     */
    public function beforeExecute ($items) {
        print_r(get_class_methods($items));die;
    }

}
```

Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\RefundOrderInterface">
        <plugin name="order-refund-checks" sortOrder="1"  disabled="false" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Order\Refund" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Using postman for testing:

POST http://dev.test/rest/V1/order/1/refund

Body JSON:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "extension_attributes": {},
            "order_item_id": 1,
            "qty": 1
        }
    ],
    "isOnline": false,
    "notify": true,
    "appendComment": true,
    "comment": {
        "extension_attributes": {},
        "comment": "refund has been created",
        "is_visible_on_front": 0
    },
    "arguments": {
        "shipping_amount": 0,
        "adjustment_positive": 0,
        "adjustment_negative": 0,
        "extension_attributes": {
            "return_to_stock_items": [
                1
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
Array
(
[0] => __construct
[1] => execute
[2] => ___init
[3] => ___callParent
[4] => __sleep
[5] => __wakeup
)
```

Screen Shot attached:
[image]

Any idea what should I do next? suggestions etc... thx.